# Play! framework : what is the difference between Router.getFullUrl("action") and Router.reverse("action").absolute()?

Tags: apache2, playframework

I need an absolute URL on my Play! 1.2.4 application as a callback for an OAuth authentication (using [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java).

My application is running behind an Apache virtual proxy, to be accessible through an URL with subdomain like "http://myapp.mydomain.com", proxying "http://127.0.0.1:9000". `ProxyPreserveHost` is set to `On`. In my Play! application configuration, I have the following property : `application.baseUrl=http://myapp.mydomain.com/`.

To compute this absolute URL, I used a piece of code like :

```
Router.ActionDefinition ad = Router.reverse("Controller.callback");
ad.absolute();
return ad.url;
```

This code worked fine with Play! 1.2.3 : it returned "http://myapp.mydomain.com/callback".

Now that I use Play! 1.2.4, this code now returns "http://www.mydomain.com:9000/callback" (translated URL by the virtual proxy without subdomain), as if Play! now used HTTP request's URL to build this absolute URL.

I empirically replaced this code to `Router.getFullUrl("Controller.callback")`, which fixes my issue.

Those two methods `Router.getFullUrl()` and `Router.absolute()` are not documented (booo!), and I was wondering the subtle differences to understand my issue.
I suppose that `Router.absolute()` uses current HTTP request to build absolute URL, and `Router.getFullUrl()` uses `application.baseUrl` configuration property.
I also may have an Apache configuration issue (as it is clearly not one of my skills!), but with `ProxyPreserveHost` set to `On`, I assumed that my virtual proxy would be transparent to Play! application, and I don't understand why it appears when switching from Play! 1.2.3 to 1.2.4.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got me curious so I went looking into the code (click to see the relevant functions directly in github). And I agree that Play! documentation is far from complete :), actually code would benefit of some more javadocs!

### Some more tests

In any case, this might be a bug... or a misuse!, there's a couple of tests you should do:

One thing you should try is the template absolute notation: `@@{…}`. Most of the time you do not need to reverse urls in your code, just in templates. Is that correct or not?

Did you try `Router.reverse("action", true)` ?

And what happens if you access directly the "localhost:9000" url from your browser, with all the different 'absolute' options?

### The code

In the 1.2.4 code:

[`String getFullUrl(...)`](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java#L320) is simply equal to `getBaseUrl() + actionDefinition=reverse(...)`

and 
[`String getBaseUrl()`](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java#L330) is defined as `application.baseUrl` ONLY IF there's no request - otherwise it uses `Http.Request.current().getBase()`.

[`ActionDefinition.absolute`](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java#L596) uses a bunch of variables from the [`reverse`](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java#L400) result.

In 1.2.3 code:

[`reverse`](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/711eb01e89c455ff69429db977c0fa973bc2e6d5/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java#L380)

[`absolute`](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/711eb01e89c455ff69429db977c0fa973bc2e6d5/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java#L584)

The `@@` tag [basically uses](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/711eb01e89c455ff69429db977c0fa973bc2e6d5/framework/src/play/templates/GroovyTemplate.java#L446):

```
private String __reverseWithCheck(String action, boolean absolute) {
    return Router.reverseWithCheck(action, Play.getVirtualFile(action), absolute);
}
```

with absolute true, that is calling directly reverse(action, absolute=true) but receiving a string rather than an ActionDefinition

### Conclusions

Maybe some play developer will step in... but i tried to help a bit, and learn in the process :) I'll let you step into the full details of comparing the two functions, but they have quite a different approach in deliverying an abs. url...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't use the template annotation `@@{}` as I do need to build this reversed URL in Java Server Code : it will be provided as a web-redirection callback for OAuth. Your investigation on getFullUrl() explains why it work using systematically getBaseUrl(), whether there is a current HTTP request or not.

Comment: @CyrilLacôte i still think there might be a bug with "absolute", but lacking both documentation and code documentation in that respect, I'd just stick to what work :)