# How do you get the full URL of a file uploaded using an Upload object in Java Play?

Tags: url, upload, playframework-1.x

I'm writing an image uploader in Java Play! in the style of

https://gist.github.com/1256286#file-picture-java-L3

This is great.  The image is rendered using this function in the `Controller` object (here, `Picture` is a `Model` implementation that has metadata about an image file:

```
public static void show(Long id) {
    Logger.info("loading id=%s", id);
    Picture picture = Picture.findByKey(id);
    response.setContentTypeIfNotSet(picture.contentType);
    renderBinary(new ByteArrayInputStream(picture.file), picture.file.length);
}
```

I want to add a `url` member to `Picture` that contains the absolute URL to this function for a given picture.  How can I populate this member in a way that works irrespective of where the Java Play! application is hosted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828985/play-framework-what-is-the-difference-between-router-getfullurlaction-and

Looks relevant ... reading through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I didn't try it in version 1.x I suggest to check the [Router API](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.5/play/mvc/Router.html), there are some methods which indicates, that they can optionally create an absolute route (I'm Play 2 user and have no experience with them).

There are also methods like ie. `getBaseUrl()` or `getFullUrl(String action, Map<String,Object> args)` so I just guess that they probably will help you to resolve the problem.

Comment: I found this method and I think it looks like the right one, but I'm not sure how you specify the route to it correctly.  For example, let's say I have a package called `somepackage` containing a class called `SomeController` with a method called `getById(long id)`.  How would I specify that to `getFullUrl( ... )` ?